# What is the mechanism when a photon is absorbed causing an electron orbital expansion to a larger orbital?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We know a photon is absorbed when an electron's orbit expands, but what is the mechanism?

We know that an electron is not simply a particle, so the photon can't be converted into only kinetic energy.

Is the photon converted into space, thus increasing the orbital size?

Comment: No, it is not converted into space.

Comment: Larger orbitals have *less* kinetic energy than smaller ones. The electron moves more *slowly* when it is farther from the nucleus.

Comment: @G.Smith - In a Bohr model, perhaps. But, take a hydrogen atom. Is the electron 'moving' in a $1s$ or a $3s$ wave function? How would one tell if it is moving at all, since those wave functions are time independent?

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, it is moving. The expectation value $\langle v^2 \rangle$ is nonzero. The Hamiltonian has a *kinetic* term.

Comment: @G.Smith - sure, but the momentum is zero (and for an $s$ state so is the angular momentum). I'm fine with Rydberg states moving (that can be seen experimentally), I'm less fine with stationary solutions being considered 'moving' in any classical or semi-classical way.

Comment: @JonCuster If we agree on the math, it doesn’t matter that we disagree on the words to describe what is going on. I guess you don’t consider a particle in a stationary state in a 1D infinite well to move either?

Comment: @G.Smith - the wave function does not move. It does not change with time. The particle can not be said to be at this point right now, and will be at that point some time later and has 'moved'.

Comment: @JonCuster If you want to consider a particle that has kinetic energy and a nonzero $\langle v^2 \rangle$ to not be “moving”, that’s fine with me. I’m not going to continue this argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photon gives the electron the energy it needs to move further away from the nucleus, against the attractive electrostatic force. In doing so, it increases the electron’s electrostatic potential energy, making it *less negative*. The kinetic energy of the electron actually *decreases*, because when the electron is further away from the nucleus it moves more slowly.

Let’s consider a specific example with the two lowest energy states of hydrogen. In the $n=1$ state, the electron has +13.6 eV of kinetic energy and -27.2 eV of potential energy, for a total energy of -13.6 eV. When a photon knocks it into the $n=2$ state, it has +3.4 eV of kinetic energy, -6.8 eV of potential energy, and -3.4 eV of total energy.

The photon transferred 10.2 eV of energy to the electron. Of this, 20.4 eV went into changing its PE, and -10.2 eV went into changing its KE.

The values I am talking about for the electron’s KE and PE are *quantum-mechanical expectation values* for these quantities. You are correct that the electron does not behave as a classical particle.

In the quantum-mechanical treatment, the primary “mechanism” of excitation is that the electric field associated with the photon interacts with the electric dipole moment of the atom. This is very similar to the classical analysis of an antenna. The electric dipole moment is due to the nucleus being positively charged and the electrons being negatively charged.

The photon is really interacting with the *atom*, not just with the *electron*. But because the nucleus barely moves compared with the electron, the kinetic energy is mainly that of the electron, and potential energy of their electrostatic interaction is often ascribed for simplicity to the electron.

Comment: What do you mean by " it increases the electron’s electrostatic potential energy, **making it less negative**"?

Comment: @Matt In the second paragraph, I gave an example where the PE goes from -27.2 eV to -6.8 eV. This is an *increase* of 20.4 eV. The PE is still negative, but it is *less negative* than it was.

Comment: @Matt You can think of “less negative” as short for “less close to negative infinity”, and similarly for the “more” and “positive” variants. So: +2 is *more positive* than +1; +1 is *less positive* than +2; -2 is *more negative* than -1; -1 is *less negative* than -2.

Comment: That was not my point, I simply had misread your sentence (I thought you said that electron was less negative, as if its charge had changed, but now I'm reading it again and I understand you're talking about the potential energy). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field of the photon pushes the electron around such that it’s wave function is now that of a higher orbital. During this interaction between charge and electric field the electric field is diminished and thus the electric field energy is converted to kinetic and potential energy of the electron particle.

Comment: If this is true, then can you pump a laser with electric fields instead of pumping a laser with photons?

Comment: You can pump a laser with electric fields. The electric fields just have to be oscillating at the right frequency such that the electrons motion is changed dramatically. For atoms “the right frequency” typically means RF microwave or optical frequencies. And of course if we have electric fields oscillating at those frequencies we call it a photon.